# Select rows that do not have the opposite value in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will only select rows that does not have the opposite value. For example if a column (payments) has 2 negative numbers(-11) and 3 positive numbers(11) both the negative numbers would cancel out and one positive number will remain. I may be explaining this wrong. But any help is  appreciated.
table :

```
CREATE TABLE hamzachecks(
   ID      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,CHECK   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,Payment VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('1','9549549544','-112.96');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('2','9549549544','-112.96');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('3','9549549544','112.96');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('4','9549549544','112.96');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('5','9549549544','-165.92');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('6','9549549544','225.92');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('7','9549549544','-299.3');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('8','9549549544','-299.3');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('9','9549549544','-299.3');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('10','9549549544','299.3');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('11','9549549544','299.3');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('12','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('13','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('14','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('15','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('16','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('17','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('18','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('19','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('20','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('21','9549549544','-415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('22','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('23','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('24','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('25','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('26','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('27','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('28','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('29','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('30','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('31','9549549544','415.14');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('32','9549549544','-1024.22');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('33','9549549544','1024.22');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('34','9549549578','-253.77');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('35','9549549578','253.77');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('36','9549549578','-3332.16');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('37','9549549578','-6664.29');
INSERT INTO hamzachecks(ID,CHECK,Payment) VALUES ('38','9549549578','6664.29');
```

Comment: so `WHERE Col1 + Col2 [+ Col3 | etc] = 0`..?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post sample data, desired output, and the results from your current coding efforts so that we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Comment: are you on rows or columns? 3 positive numbers(11) would already put you at +11 (one over the two * -11) .

Comment: If there are three rows with positive numbers and only two rows with negative numbers, how do you know which of the three positive rows is the one that doesn't have an opposite value?   In other words, which of the three positive rows do you want to return?

Comment: I would expect that the check number would be different...is it really the same check for all those different transactions?

Comment: yes, its the same check,

Comment: select [Check], Sum( cast(Payment as int ))
from #hamzachecks
group by [Check]

Comment: it should return the last number that is left. so between ID (7-11) only ID(9) should be returned

Comment: out of the table only rows where id is 5,6,9, and 36 should be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to ignore possible considerations for why you want to do this particular job in this particular way.

So basically: the following SQL will give you the result you are asking for...

```
;with b (id, payment, rn) as 
(select id, payment, row_number() over (partition by Payment order by Id) as rn 
from hamzachecks 
where payment < 0),
a (id, payment, rn) as 
(select id, payment, row_number() over (partition by Payment order by Id) as rn 
from hamzachecks 
where payment > 0),
matched_ids (id1,id2) as 
(select a.id id1, b.id id2 
from a 
join b on a.payment = -b.payment and a.rn = b.rn)
select *
from hamzachecks
where id not in (select id1 from matched_ids union select id2 from matched_ids)
order by id
```

This needs a change in your schema: define the Payment column as `MONEY` (or other number type) instead of `VARCHAR(8)`.
This would be a starting point for further work, as this solution is ignoring the `CHECK` column.

Explanation: first we split the source table into two groups: `a` - above zero (`payment > 0`) and `b` - below zero (`payment < 0`). Both of those groups will get another column `row_number() ...` that get gets each row an "rowID" - based on the position in the particular group (`partition by Payment`) that basically says: "This is *n-th* row with the same Payment". The join part then matches all rows that have the same (but opposite) Payment in the other group and also checks the rowID - we now know all rows that have an opposite value. So the main select just ignores those rows and return only those that don't have an opposite value.

Comment: @TheRealHamzaYusuf if you're happy with the solution, please mark it as answer, thanks

Comment: What would be another way of doing this ? Also, what is the logic behind this: 
  join b on a.payment = -b.payment and a.rn = b.rn

Comment: @TheRealHamzaYusuf I added an explanation to the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic is the same as @Marty's, assign a row number to each row in with the same `chk/payment` combination.

```
SELECT chk
  ,id 
  ,Payment
  ,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY chk, Payment ORDER BY Id) AS rn 
FROM hamzachecks 
order by 
   chk
   -- remove the leading '-'', for numeric data: abs(Payment)
  ,substring(Payment, charindex('-', Payment)+1, 8000)
  ,rn
  ,Payment
```

It there's a matching row both rows will share the same `rn`

```
... 
9549549544      3       112.96     1 -- 1st group
9549549544      1      -112.96     1    --  matching value: remove
9549549544      4       112.96     2 -- 2nd group 
9549549544      2      -112.96     2    --  matching value: remove
...
9549549544      10      299.3      1 -- 1st group
9549549544      7      -299.3      1    --  matching value: remove
9549549544      11      299.3      2 -- 2nd group
9549549544      8      -299.3      2    --  matching value: remove
9549549544      9      -299.3      3 -- 3rd group, no matching value: keep
...
```

Now remove the groups with two rows using aggregation:

```
;WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT chk
     ,id 
     ,Payment
     ,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY chk, Payment ORDER BY Id) AS rn 
   FROM hamzachecks 
 )
SELECT
   Min(id)
  ,chk
  ,max(Payment)
FROM cte
GROUP BY
   chk
   -- remove the leading '-'', for numeric data: abs(Payment)
  ,substring(Payment, charindex('-', Payment)+1, 8000)
  ,rn
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=efd7419c82f25d388bceae65d4ce9098)